# Moxy fragment kills after unsuccessful api call

Tags: android, android-fragments, moxy, clean-architecture

I'm using Clean Architecture, in presentation layer I'm using Moxy MVP, for data flow RxJava2.
Problem with executing use case. When I call use case it returns DisposableObserver. If onNext() was called all works perfect, but if use case returns an error (for some reason, network connecting for instance) fragment destroys and recreates immediately.

BaseFragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : MvpAppCompatFragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return (inflater.inflate(getLayoutResource(), container, false) as View)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    bindUI()
}

protected abstract fun bindUI()

abstract fun getLayoutResource(): Int

protected fun <C> getComponent(componentType: Class<C>): C {
    return componentType.cast((activity as HasComponent<*>).component)
}
}
```

Target fragment:

```
class NotesListFragment : BaseFragment(), NotesListView {

@InjectPresenter lateinit var presenter: NotesListPresenter
@Inject lateinit var notesListAdapter: NotesListAdapter

override fun bindUI() {
    getComponent(MainComponent::class.java).inject(this)
    presenter.getAssignmentsWithNotes()
}

override fun getLayoutResource(): Int = R.layout.fragment_notes_list
}
```

Target presenter:

```
@InjectViewState
class NotesListPresenter : BasePresenter<NotesListView>() {

@Inject lateinit var router: Router
@Inject lateinit var assignmentsWithNotesUseCase: GetAssignmentsWithNotesUseCase

private var assignmentsWithNotes = mutableListOf<AssignmentWithNote>()

init {
    BTApplication.getApplicationComponent()?.mainComponent()?.inject(this)
}

fun getAssignmentsWithNotes() {
    assignmentsWithNotesUseCase.execute(
            onNext = {
                assignmentsWithNotes.addAll(it)
            },
            onError = {
                Timber.e(it) //problem appears here                 
            })
}
}
```

Here is what I can see in logs:

> E/NotesListFragment: onCreate NoteListFragment
>
> D/OkHttp: --> GET http://.....com/api/assignments/notes?start=0&rows=25
>
> D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>
> E/NotesListFragment: on destroy NotesListFragment
>   E/NotesListFragment: onCreate NoteListFragment
>
> D/OkHttp: --> GET http://.....com/api/assignments/notes?start=0&rows=25

In the project I have many typical realizations which works fine.